# CollectionView willDisplayCell called twice

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I'm having a problem with

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{}
```

I'm using this method to determine that the last cell will be displayed and then make a network request to pull more data. This works fine until I make the request again from the last row (when one of my BOOLS is false) eg:

```
    -(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
       if (indexPath.item = [self.collectionView.datasource count]-1 && self.moreVendorsAvaiable) {
      [network request:^(id response,id error){
      if (!error){
      [self processResponse:response];
       }                

        }];
     }
 }

- (void) parseMoreVendors:(id)response{
//If response is > 0, there are more vendors to retrieve
NSLog(@"response");
if ([response count]>0) {
    id parsedObject = nil;
    NSMutableArray *vendorsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.datasource.content[@"rows"];
    NSMutableArray *updates = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    FeaturedHeader *header = self.datasource.content[@"header"];
    Vendor *firstFeatured = header.firstFeatured;
    Vendor *secondFeatured = header.secondFeatured;

    for (id object in response) {
        //check if the response object is a featured vendor and return if it is
        if ( [firstFeatured.vendorId isEqual:object[@"id"]] || [secondFeatured.vendorId isEqual:object[@"id"]] ){
            self.featuredReturned = YES;
            return;
        }
        parsedObject = [[Vendor alloc] initWithDictionary:object];
        [updates addObject:parsedObject];
    }

    [vendorsArray addObjectsFromArray:updates];

    NSDictionary *content = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:header, @"header", vendorsArray, @"rows", nil];

    [self.datasource setContent:content];
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}else{
    self.moreVendorsAvailable = NO;
}
```

}

When the data is retrieved and the datasource is updated I call collectionView reloadData. The data is reloaded and since I'm in the bottom cell the network request is made again and it then pulls the same data again. How can I prevent it from making a network request again?

Comment: could you able to share whole class code ???

Comment: @muhammadRaheelMateen I've added the code that processes the network request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before iterating though all of your response objects, just check to make sure the `venderId` of your last dataSource object doesn't match the `venderId` of your last response object (since in that case you would have already retrieved all of the Vendors). Here is the pseudocode:

```
if (lastDataSource.venderId isEqual:object[@"id"])
{
  moreVendorsAvailable = NO;
  return;

}
```

Comment: thanks your reply. What I'm trying to do is pull more data as the user scrolls to the last cell. Currently our data is not big but it will grow in the near future so it will be making multiple request as the data grows. I think what you suggested I have already implemented with the BOOL moreVendorsToRetrieve. My issue is when moreVendorsToRetrieve is false/NO and the last cell is being displayed and then a refresh call is made so the datasource is repopulated and reloaddata is called and since the last cell is visible the method in willdisplaycell is called.

Comment: And also the moreVendorsToRetrieve is a typo. It should be moreVendorsAvailable.

Comment: @Pablo I have edited my answer based on the additional information.

Comment: Ok, so I have plugged it into the `for (id object in response)` loop and it seems to working. Would you say it is more efficient to do it this way:




`Vendor *lastVendor = [self.datasource.content[@"rows"]objectAtIndex:[self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:0]-1];`


`id lastObject = [response objectAtIndex:[response count]-1];`
        
`if ([lastVendor.vendorId isEqual:lastObject[@"id"]])`
 `NSLog(@"hope %@ this works %@",lastVendor.vendorName, lastObject[@"name"]);`
            `self.moreVendorsAvailable = NO;`
            `return;`
 }

Comment: @pablo it's more efficient to check before the `for` loop since otherwise you'll have to iterate through all the vendors before finding the match.

Comment: thank you so much for your help! I had been stuck with this for hours.